# Parsing JSON into parent-child object using JSON.Net

Tags: json, json.net

I have some order data that is in JSON format that I would like to populate a custom object with. Looking at JSON.net documentation it appears I can use [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithLinq.htm) to deserializec JSON to a .NET type. My question is can you do this with a class that references another custom class as a property?

Assume I have two classes `Order` and `OrderDetail`. Where `Order` has a property that contains a collection of `OrderDetail` objects.

```
class Order
{
  public string OrderId {get; set;}
  public string OrderDescription {get; set;}
  public List<OrderDetail> OrderItems {get; set;} // Collection of OrderDetails
}

class OrderDetail
{
  public string ProductId {get; set;}
  public string ProductName {get; set;}
  public string UnitPrice {get; set;}
  public int Quantity {get; set;}
}
```

Can LINQ to JSON be used to query the data and populate the objects?

**Here is some sample JSON**

```
{
  "orders": [{
      "orderId": 111,
      "orderDescription": "Giant Food Mart",
      "orderItems": [{
          "productId": 65,
          "productName": "Dried Beef",
          "unitPrice": 10.00,
          "quantity": 7
        },
        {
          "productId": 23,
          "productName": "Carrots",
          "unitPrice": 1.25,
          "quantity": 100
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "orderId": 112,
      "orderDescription": "Bob's Corner Variety",
      "orderItems": [{
          "productId": 523,
          "productName": "Red Licorice",
          "unitPrice": 0.50,
          "quantity": 27
        },
        {
          "productId": 321,
          "productName": "Gummy Worms",
          "unitPrice": 1.50,
          "quantity": 50
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It is how to parse the `OrderItems` into the **Orderitems** property of the `Order` object that is confusing me

```
JArray parsedJson = JArray.Parse("JSON data here");

IList<Order> orders = parsedJson.Select(x => new Order
{
    OrderId = (int)x["orderId"],
    OrderDescription = (string)x["orderDescription"],
    OrderItems = x["orderItems"], // Here is where I get stuck
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close, this worked using linq and you'll get everything in your orders list.

```
var parsedJson = JObject.Parse(test);

var orders = parsedJson.Values().Children()
.Select(x => new Order
{
    OrderId = (int)x["orderId"],
    OrderDescription = (string)x["orderDescription"],
    OrderItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< List<OrderDetail>>(x["orderItems"].ToString()) 
}).ToList();
```

Note: I had to change:

```
public string OrderId { get; set; } //you were casting to int but had a string.
```

to

```
public int OrderId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing my error :) and for the solution. I like the method because it is more flexible in cases where the JSON property names might not be the same names as the class properties. In my example they are the same, but I only did that to remove as much confusion as possible and make the questions easier to read and understand.

Comment: One followup question ... If the data I need is nested down in the JSON can I specify the node name (property name) where the Order Data begins? I notice you used the `children()` method. I am assuming you used that three times to "dive" into the JSON to get the node you wanted? The node I want is off of the root level and is named "transactionData".

Comment: @webworm Let me edit my answer to include the transactionData node.

Comment: Thanks for the update! The only part I am not getting is `.Children().Children().Children()`. Why three instances?

Comment: I updated the answer to remove the number children calls, it just basically gets the child nodes. I also removed the transactionData node since it isn't in your original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166855/discussion-between-ismael-and-webworm).

Answer (score 2):

You're making this harder than it needs to be. Use [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com) to generate your classes to match the JSON.

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public int productId { get; set; }
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public double unitPrice { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int orderId { get; set; }
    public string orderDescription { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> orderItems { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Order> orders { get; set; }
}
```

Then simply deserialize into those classes.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(myJsonString);
```

At this point you can use LINQ-to-Objects to do any queries you might need to.

Comment: I had not thought about using a `RootObject` to contain the collection of `Orders`. Great idea! If I do not need all the data from the JSON data will JSON.Net just pull out the data referenced in the classes? For example say that the JSON has extra Order information such as "delivery address" or something else. This information is not required by the class `Order` so will the JSON.Net parser pull out only `OrderId`, `OrderDescription` and `OrderDetail` and ignore the rest of the data?

Comment: Extra values in the JSON will simply be dropped on the floor and if there are values in the class definition that don't exist in the JSON they'll be set to the correct default value for the type.